# Deployment error:Starting of Tomcat failed, the server port 198 is already in use. See the server log for details

Tags: netbeans

I am getting this error while I am trying to run java web program in my netbeans[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1k6H.png).

Can anyone please help?
How to solve this problem?

Comment: can you add more details about your code?

Comment: Hey Christopher, actually I have recently installed apache-tomcat in my linux os,and I have added Apache server in netbeans.When I am trying to run the program,Iam getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Since the port 198 is being, used you either need to use a different port, or stop the program using that port. Use some sort of [port scan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows) to find out what program is using the port and resolve it from there. It says to check the server logs, and it is also possible that you are trying to run multiple instances of your program.

Comment: actually I have recently installed apache-tomcat and I have added server in netbeans.When trying to run the program,Iam getting  error Program is below                                                                                                          <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--

-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tomcat</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>installing apache server in netbeans</div>
    </body>
</html>